# How to create a field consisting of a list of all nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Good day.

There is a problem: display news block on specific pages of any type of material.

I see the solution as follows: Create a field in the type of material "News" which will be displayed all the nodes (Title) with the possibility of using the mark checkboxes.

Who could help with advice: is it the right direction, and if yes - how to realize this field?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and enable [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) and [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) modules.

Then go to your content type "Manage fields" page (`admin/structure/types/manage/[CONTENT_TYPE]/fields`) and add a new field of type `Node reference`. The rest of the configuration is left for your liking.

Comment: Yes it is! You considerably simplified my Drupal learning and development. Thank you a lot =)